# Parsing a string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let's say I have a string like this "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456" in a notepad file and I want to load each INDIVIDUAL character into a list in python. How would I go about doing that? With a for loop?

Comment: `list(s)` will do it, but you can iterate over a string directly so depending on your use case you may not need to: `for c in s:` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a file called `file.txt` with the following contents:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456
```

You could add each character manually:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  line = f.readline()  # assumes there is only one line in the file you want to read
  char_list = []
  for c in line:
    char_list.append(c)
  # Same thing using a list comprehension
  # char_list = [c for c in line]
  print(char_list)
```

or use alternatively just call [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) on the line:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  line = f.readline()  # assumes there is only one line in the file you want to read
  char_list = list(line)
  print(char_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```